# Native events error for Selenium WebDriver 2.35.0 and Firefox 23.0.1

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to perform drag and drop operation by following on Firefox 23.0.1 browser with Selenium WebDriver 2.35.0:

`driver.action.drag_and_drop(source, target).perform`

but it results into:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot perform native interaction: Could not load native events component.`
```

Even though [change log](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/rb/CHANGES) says:

```
2.35.0 (2013-08-14)
===================

Firefox:
  * Updated Firefox native event components to support Firefox 23.
```

why native events error is thrown with Selenium WebDriver 2.35.0 and Firefox 23.0.1 combination?

I asked same question twice on #selenium irc channel, but no one replied to it. Help me to understand if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Mostly because the new versions of Firefox break selenium.

Comment: But change log says it should work with Selenium webriver 2.35.0 and Firefox 23(As I mentioned in the question itself)

Comment: But you are using Firefox 23.0.`1`

Comment: I think, it should support all 23.x.x as they said `Firefox 23`